# Unicity of wave equation pde problem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

we consider the problem
$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}= a^2 \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\\
u(0,t)=u(l,t)=0\\
u(x,0)=f(x)\\
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,0)=g(x)
\end{cases}
$$
I want to prove the unicity of the solution of this problem. For this, we put $f=g=0$, we multiply the equation by $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ and integrate in $[0,l]$. Using that 
$$
\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial t} w= \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} w^2,
$$
we obtain that 
$$
\dfrac{1}{2} \displaystyle\int_0^l \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} \{(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t})^2+a^2 (\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x})^2\} dx =0.
$$
We put 
$$
I(t)= \dfrac{1}{2} \displaystyle\int_0^l \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} \{(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t})^2+a^2 (\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x})^2\} dx.
$$

My question is: how do we prove that 
$$
\forall t \geq 0: I(t)=I(0)
$$
and how do we deduce the unicity of the solution $u$? Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are meant to set
$$
I(t)= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^l  \left\{\left(\frac{∂u}{∂t}\right)^2+a^2 \left(\frac{∂u}{∂x}\right)^2\right\} dx
$$
so that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}I(t) 
= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^l \frac{∂}{∂t} \left\{\left(\frac{∂u}{∂t}\right)^2+a^2 \left(\frac{∂u}{∂x}\right)^2\right\} dx=0
$$
which implies that $I$ is a constant function.

---

As to the uniqueness, any difference between two solutions solves the homogeneous equation with homogeneous boundary conditions. As $I(0)=0$, the difference function has zero gradient everywhere, thus has to be constant zero.

Comment: And how we deduce the unicity of $u$?Pease

Comment: I don't understand, why to prouve solution we put $f=g=0$. Why? Please.

Comment: If there are two solutions $u_1,u_2$ then their difference $v=u_2-u_1$ satisfies the same wave equation, but with zero boundary conditions. The calculation shows that $∂_tv=0=∂_xv$ so that $v$ is constant. By the boundary conditions, this constant is zero. Thus $u_1=u_2$.